# StructType can not accept object 'books' in type <class 'str'>

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

hello am new to pyspark am trying to to load json as a dataframe by enforcing schema in StructType but facing error

### my json:

```py
jsn = {"books": [{"book_id": "B001","book_name": "The Great Gatsby","author": "F. Scott Fitzgerald","copies_available": 5},{"book_id": "B002","book_name": "To Kill a Mockingbird","author": "Harper Lee","copies_available": 3}]}
```

### schema

```py
js_schema = StructType([
    StructField("books",ArrayType(StructType([StructField("book_id",StringType()),StructField("book_name",StringType()),StructField("author",StringType()),StructField("copies_available",IntegerType())])))
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(jsn,js_schema)
```

now when i try to create a dataframe am getting above errors:

```
"TypeError(new_msg("StructType can not accept object %r in type %s"
                                        % (obj, type(obj))))"

StructType can not accept object 'books' in type <class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 2):

`spark.createDataFrame` expects an Iterable as its input. Your `jsn` object is a dictionary and dictionaries are indeed Iterable, but not in the way you might want here. It is more intuitive to give a list as input to `spark.createDataFrame`.

For both of the following methods, you don't have to define a `js_schema` (because the structure is already inside of your dictionary).

#### Option 1

You could turn your `jsn` object into a list by enclosing it between `[]` characters:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([jsn])

>>> df.show()
+--------------------+
|               books|
+--------------------+
|[{copies_availabl...|
+--------------------+

>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- books: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

So you see that you have a schema as exists in your data: `books` is an array of structs. But then you end up with this `element` within your array that is of type `map`. You can work with this but there is another option to have it easier.

#### Option 2

If you want to immediately have your data in columns (so not having to process that `map` column), you can also simply supply the `books` array as input itself:

```py
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(jsn['books'])

>>> df2.show()
+-------------------+-------+--------------------+----------------+
|             author|book_id|           book_name|copies_available|
+-------------------+-------+--------------------+----------------+
|F. Scott Fitzgerald|   B001|    The Great Gatsby|               5|
|         Harper Lee|   B002|To Kill a Mocking...|               3|
+-------------------+-------+--------------------+----------------+

>>> df2.printSchema()
root
 |-- author: string (nullable = true)
 |-- book_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- book_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- copies_available: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: i would need to define the schema based on the StructType Schema enforcement inorder to pass user required datatypes rather than spark infered ones. could you please tell us if there is a way we can enforce schema based on StructType.  Ex: spark.createDataFrame(jsn,required_schema) where spark is sparksession variable

Comment: Us reviewers here are certainly happy to help with that! :) For your second question that you posed here as a comment, I propose that you close off this question (since it was answered) and create a new question post. Here on Stackoverflow, we strive for our questions and answers to be focused so that they are clear and easier to look up for future readers.